# CSS float:right isn't applying

Tags: html, css, image, class, css-float

http://www.fccorp.us/_projects/jfx.projects.s4a.php

The first and third image have a class="imgright" in the html tag, yet the properties aren't being applied.

The second image has a class="imgleft" in the tag, and it IS working.

The CSS:

```
.imgright {float:right; margin:3px; margin-left:20px;}
.imgleft {float:left; margin:3px; margin-right:20px;}
```

The HTML (the image tag):

```
<img src="../_pic-lib/_projects/fcrr-2-v1.png" class="imgright" style="margin-bottom:1px !important; -moz-force-broken-image-icon:1;" width="488" height="193" alt="Missing S.4.a Image" />

<img src="../_pic-lib/_projects/fcrr-2-v2.png" class="imgleft" style="margin-bottom:1px !important;-moz-force-broken-image-icon:1;" width="400" height="267" alt="Missing S.4.a Image" />
```

And of course, you can view the page sources at http://www.fccorp.us/_projects/jfx.projects.s4a.php

What little, obvious thing am I missing? What really gets me is that this all worked fine the other day when the pages were in website's root directory. I just don't know what I changed accidentally since then that broke this.

Thanx,
-J.D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a stray `.engname` in your style sheet at line 67 that is disabling the styles that follow.

Comment: that was the answer, thank you very much. I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

in css file named "fccorp-us.css" at line no 67 there is a class named ".engname" which dont have opening and closing tag.

```
.engname{}
```